# Use IntelliJ IDEA for Dart

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, google-chrome-app

Does anyone know why he disappeared support of chrome app in the transition from Dart Editor to IntelliJ?

Can't launch background.js but only the HTML files

What can you use to develop chrome app?

Answer (score 1):

The feature is not available in WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEA at the moment. Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12096

Comment: Solved using Eclipse but now do not work the auto-completion. Dart editor was much better.